# Lex program to count number of lines, characters, digits, and key words

Tags: c, regex, lex

I have been working on developing a lex scanner however when I feed it my input file it is producing the wrong output. Here is my source code:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>

int NumberOfLines=0;
int NumberOfChar=0;
int NumberOfIntegers=0;
int KWCount=0;
int NumberOfComments=0;
%}

DIGIT   [0-9]*
ID  [a-z][a-z0-9]*
%x COMMENT
%option noyywrap
%%

^[\t]*"/*" {BEGIN COMMENT;}
^[\t]*"/*".*"*/"[\t]*\n {NumberOfComments++;}

<COMMENT>"*/"[\t]*\n {BEGIN 0; NumberOfComments++;}
<COMMENT>"*/" {BEGIN 0;}
<COMMENT>\n {NumberOfComments++;}
<COMMENT>.\n {NumberOfComments++;}

\n {NumberOfLines++, NumberOfChar++; NumberOfChar +=strlen(yytext);}
. {NumberOfChar++; NumberOfChar +=strlen(yytext);}



{DIGIT}     {NumberOfIntegers++; NumberOfChar +=strlen(yytext); }


{DIGIT}+"."{DIGIT}* {
    printf("A flot: %s (%g) \n", yytext, atof(yytext));
    NumberOfChar +=strlen(yytext); 
    }

if|else|while|return    {
    printf("A keyword: %s\n", yytext); KWCount++;
    NumberOfChar +=strlen(yytext); 
    }

{ID}        {
    printf("An identifier: %s\n", yytext);
    NumberOfChar +=strlen(yytext); 
    }
"{"[^}\n]*"}"   {
    /*each up one-line comments*/
    NumberOfChar +=strlen(yytext);
    }

%%
int main(int argc, char **argv){
    ++argv, --argc; /*skip over program name */
    if (argc > 0)
        yyin = fopen(argv[0], "r"); 
    else
        yyin = stdin; 
    yylex();
    printf("Character count: %d",NumberOfChar);
    printf("\n");
    printf("Number count: %d",NumberOfIntegers);
    printf("\n");
    printf("Keyword count: %d",KWCount);
    printf("\n");
    printf("Line count: %d",NumberOfLines);
    printf("\n");
    printf("Comment count: %d", NumberOfComments);
    printf("\n"); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Whenever I run my input file with the source it give me the wrong output. For instance the output of the file should be:

Output:

```
Number of Keywords: 3

Number of Characters: 196

Number of Lines: 17

Number of Digits: 3
```

However the output it is currently producing is:

Output:

```
Number of keywords: 0

Number of Characters: 3

Number of Lines: 7

Number of Digits: 0
```

I suspect it has to do with my regular expressions, any help would be appreciated as I am still learning regex!

Here is my input file contents:

```
/*comment 1*/
/*comment
  comment 2 
  */
  /*comment 3*
   */if this is a line
{comment 4}
int i = 789; 
int j = 689;
if i == 172 then
 {comment 5}
else
{comment 6}
{comment 7}
/*8 comments
 *
 */ 
end
```

Comment: What's the input? Also, your output doesn't match the `printf` calls in your code.

Comment: @ForceBru Sorry I wrote it in the wrong order, there are other things that will display however I was focusing on the particular output that was wrong. I have the input file just not sure of how to post it?

Comment: Just like you posted the code, as `formatted text`, in your question.

Comment: @ForceBru there you go, I am supposed to silently skip over the comments but still keep the character count. Not sure why "{comment}" is considered a comment but I am supposed to ignore.

Comment: Keep in mind that `lex` does the first match only.

Comment: You aren't incrementing `KWCount` anywhere.  You aren't counting upper-case letter anywhere.  Your `.` rule is earlier than I'd expect — it should normally be the last rule.  It may not matter here where your rules do not return, but normally (in grammars) the rules return in the action code, and then you would have problems (the digits, keywords and identifiers would not be recognized).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I believe I incremented 'KWCount' now. However it still isn't registering? For the upper case are you talking about utilizing the regex?: "^[A-Z]+$"

Comment: Only in the second version (and any later versions) of the code, not in the original code on which I commented.

Comment: Ok, I have updated the code however I am still having issues with the Character count, I believe it has to do with that I need to skip comments. I tried a few regex but they would eat up all of text. Any ideas?

Comment: Use `input()` in the action for comments until you come across the end of comment marker.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Not really sure how to do that is there a reference page you know of off hand so that I can try to deduce it myself?

Comment: There's the official manual — https://westes.github.io/flex/manual/ (for version 2.6.2; the latest version is 2.6.4, but the differences are probably small).  The source is on GitHub at https://github.com/westes/flex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some mostly working code, closely based on your code.

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>

int NumberOfLines=0;
int NumberOfChar=0;
int NumberOfIntegers=0;
int KWCount = 0;
int IDCount = 0;
int RCCount = 0;
int OCCount = 0;
int DTCount = 0;
int FLCount = 0;
%}

%option noyywrap
%option noinput
%option nounput

DIGIT   [0-9]*
ID  [a-z][a-z0-9]*

%%

\n {NumberOfLines++; NumberOfChar++; RCCount += strlen(yytext); }
. {NumberOfChar++; DTCount++; RCCount++; printf(" '%c'", yytext[0]); }

{DIGIT}     {NumberOfIntegers++; RCCount += strlen(yytext); }

{DIGIT}+"."{DIGIT}* {
    printf("\nA float: %s (%g) \n", yytext, atof(yytext)); 
    RCCount += strlen(yytext);
    FLCount++;
    }

if|else|while|return    {
    printf("\nA keyword: %s\n", yytext); 
    KWCount++;
    RCCount += strlen(yytext);
    }

{ID}        {
    printf("\nAn identifier: %s\n", yytext); 
    IDCount++;
    RCCount += strlen(yytext);
    }
"{"[^}\n]*"}"   {
    RCCount += strlen(yytext);
    OCCount += strlen(yytext);
    }

%%
int main(int argc, char **argv){
    ++argv, --argc; /*skip over program name */
    if (argc > 0)
        yyin = fopen(argv[0], "r"); 
    else
        yyin = stdin; 
    yylex();
    printf("Character count: %d\n", NumberOfChar);
    printf("Number count:    %d\n", NumberOfIntegers);
    printf("Keyword count:   %d\n", KWCount);
    printf("Line count:      %d\n", NumberOfLines);
    printf("ID count:        %d\n", IDCount);
    printf("Dot count:       %d\n", DTCount);
    printf("Raw count:       %d\n", RCCount);
    printf("Float count:     %d\n", FLCount);
    printf("Other count:     %d\n", OCCount);
    printf("\n"); 
    return 0; 
}
```

When run on the data file:

```
/*commEnt 1*/
/*COMMENT
  commEnt 2 
  */
  /*commEnt 3*
   */if this is a linE
{commEnt 4}
int i = 789; 
int j = 689;
if i == 172 thEn
 {commEnt 5}
ElsE
{commEnt 6}
{commEnt 7}
float 12.34
/*8 commEnts
 *
 else
 return
 while
 the
 going
 is
 good
 */ 
end
```

I get the output:

```
 '/' '*'
An identifier: comm
 'E'
An identifier: nt
 ' ' '1' '*' '/' '/' '*' 'C' 'O' 'M' 'M' 'E' 'N' 'T' ' ' ' '
An identifier: comm
 'E'
An identifier: nt
 ' ' '2' ' ' ' ' ' ' '*' '/' ' ' ' ' '/' '*'
An identifier: comm
 'E'
An identifier: nt
 ' ' '3' '*' ' ' ' ' ' ' '*' '/'
A keyword: if
 ' '
An identifier: this
 ' '
An identifier: is
 ' ' 'a' ' '
An identifier: lin
 'E'
An identifier: int
 ' ' 'i' ' ' '=' ' ' ';' ' '
An identifier: int
 ' ' 'j' ' ' '=' ' ' ';'
A keyword: if
 ' ' 'i' ' ' '=' '=' ' ' ' '
An identifier: th
 'E' 'n' ' ' 'E'
An identifier: ls
 'E'
An identifier: float
 ' '
A float: 12.34 (12.34) 
 '/' '*' '8' ' '
An identifier: comm
 'E'
An identifier: nts
 ' ' '*' ' '
A keyword: else
 ' '
A keyword: return
 ' '
A keyword: while
 ' '
An identifier: the
 ' '
An identifier: going
 ' '
An identifier: is
 ' '
An identifier: good
 ' ' '*' '/' ' '
An identifier: end
Character count: 115
Number count:    3
Keyword count:   5
Line count:      26
ID count:        21
Dot count:       89
Raw count:       258
Float count:     1
Other count:     44
```

The output from `wc` is:

```
$ wc data.2
      26      49     258 data.2
$
```

The 'raw count' of characters matches the character count from `wc`; the line count matches too.  The number of integers, floats, keywords and identifiers all looks correct, given that upper case letters are counted in the 'dot characters'.  You can work out whether there are other problems; I think that the count of integers is wrong, but I'm not sure why.

Comment: Thank you! I just updated the code, I believe that my only other problem is to skip comments which I believe is why I am getting a incorrect output for Char Count.